# pthread_join hangs accordingly to random global variable value

Tags: c, pthreads, freeze, pthread-join

I have built this code utilizing pthreads. The goal is to build an array `X[N][D]` and assign random values to it. You could read the elements of this array as the coefficients of some points.

On the next step I am trying to calculate an array `distances[N]`which holds all the distances between the last element (`N`th) and each other element. The distances calculation is executed using `pthreads`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 10
#define D 2         //works for any d
#define NUM_THREADS 8


//double *distances;
//int global_index = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
double *X;

typedef struct
{
    //int thread_id;
    double *distances;
    int *global_index ;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    double *X;

}parms;

void *threadDistance(void *arg)
{
    parms *data = (parms *) arg;
    double *distances = data->distances;
    double *X = data->X;
    int *global_idx = data -> global_index;

    int idx,j;
    //long id = (long)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    while(*global_idx<N)
    {
        //printf("Thread #%ld , is calculating\n", id);
        idx = *(global_idx);
        (*global_idx)++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        for(j=0 ; j<D; j++)
        {
            distances[idx] = pow(X[(j+1)*N-1]-X[j*N+idx], 2);
            //printf("dis[%d]= ", dis);
            //printf("%f\n",distances[idx]);
        }
        //printf("global : %d\n", *global_idx);
    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);


}

void calcDistance(double * X, int n, int d)
{
    int i;
    int temp=0;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    double *distances = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    parms arg;
    arg.X = X;
    arg.distances = distances;
    arg.global_index = &temp;

    for (i=0 ; i<NUM_THREADS ; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadDistance, (void *) &arg);
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    /*----print dstances[] array-------*/
    printf("--------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", distances[i]);
    }
    /*------------*/
    free(distances);
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    //allocate the proper space for X
    X = malloc(D*N*(sizeof(double)));

    //fill X with numbers in space (0,1)
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<D; j++)
        {
            X[i+j*N] = (double) (rand()  / (RAND_MAX + 2.0));
        }

    }

    calcDistance(X, N, D);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the code executes completely only when `N=100000`. If `N!=100000` the code just hangs and I have found that the source of the problem is the `pthread_join()` function. First of all I cannot understand why the hang depends on the value of `N`.

Secondly, I have tried `printf()`ing the value of `global_index` (as you can see it is commented out in this particular sample of code). As soon as I uncomment the `printf("global : %d\n", *global_idx);` command the program stops hanging, regardless of the value of `N`.

*It seems crazy to me as the differences between hanging and not hanging are so irrelevant.*

Comment: you have some issues with your mutexes, e.g. within `while(*global_idx<N)` you unlock, but you don't lock again so the next accesss is unsynchronized. Also you should unlock before exiting the thread. Maybe that solved the problem, the behaviour you've experienced smells like a race condition for me

Comment: `free(distances);` and `printf("%f\n", distances[i]);` - you are accessing freeed memory.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt thank you. That was the problem. Still don't get why on different values of N it didn't hang.

Comment: in function: `calcdistance()`  the first two loops use the instance of a variable named `i` that is a local variable to the function,  Then the third loop uses a variable inside the body of the loop, named `i`.   This 'shadows' the original variable `i`   Suggest each of the loops define a variable `i` as it is best to limit the scope of variables.

Comment: declaring a `pthread_mutex_t` both inside the `struct` and at file scope is a problem,  Suggest removing the declaration in the struct.   Also,  mutex variables should be initialized, similar to:    `pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadDistance, (void *) &arg);`   always check the returned value (should be 0) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `X = malloc(D*N*(sizeof(double)));`   The allocated memory is never passed to `free()` so the program has a massive memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
while(*global_idx<N) 
{  
    // ... 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

The result is that after the first iteration of the loop, the mutex is always unlocked. Suggest moving the call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` to inside the top of the loop.

after making the above corrections, I then set `N` to 10000.  Then re-compiled, etc.  The result was a seg fault event, so the mis-handling of the mutex is not the only problem.

regarding:

```
* First of all I cannot understand why the hang depends on the value of N.*
```

it seems the program is actually crashing with a seg fault event,  not hanging